# Codeigniter select join giving duplicate results

Tags: php, postgresql, codeigniter

Hi everyone so I am having trouble of creating a query in codeigniter model which will give me this result. So far I have these tables on my database. and I'm trying using join and it's not working for me. It will just display duplicate songs and different publisher/writer. Here's my current query from my model.

```
public function get_songs_in_playlist($playlist_id)
{
    $this->db->select(
        "si.song_info_file_name, 
        si.song_info_revised_file_name, 
        a.artist_name, 
        si.song_info_id as songinfoid,
        array_to_string(array_agg(c.composer_name),'/'),
        array_to_string(array_agg(p.publisher_name),'/'), 
        array_to_string(array_agg(st.tag_name),',')"
    );
    $this->db->from('songs_in_playlist sp');
    $this->db->join('song_info si', 'sp.song_info_id = si.song_info_id', 'left');
    $this->db->join('original_artist a', 'si.artist_id = a.artist_id', 'left');
    $this->db->join('composer c', 'si.composer_id = c.composer_id', 'left');
    $this->db->join('publisher p', 'si.publisher_id = p.publisher_id', 'left');
    $this->db->join('song_info_tags sit', 'si.song_info_id = sit.song_info_id', 'left');
    $this->db->join('song_tags st', 'st.tag_id = sit.tag_id', 'left');
    $this->db->where('sp.playlist_id', $playlist_id);
    $this->db->group_by(array("si.song_info_id", "a.artist_name", "c.composer_name" , "p.publisher_name" ));

    $query = $this->db->get();


    return $query->result_array();

}
```

Song Table

```
song_info_id   song_name
1              songA
```

Publisher Table

```
publisher_id   publisher_name
1              publisherA
2              publisherB
```

Writer Table

```
writer_id      writer_name     song_info_id    publisher_id
1              writerA         1               1
2              writerB         1               2
```

Result should be:

```
Song Name      Writers                Publishers
SongA          writerA, writerB       publisherA, publisherB
```

Current result from join:

```
Song Name      Writers                Publishers
SongA          writerA                publisherA
SongA          writerB                publisherB
```

Results in array

```
Array ( 
    [0] => Array ( 
        [song_info_file_name] => Cartoon_-_On_On_(ft__Daniel_Levi).mp3 
        [song_info_revised_file_name] => 1510657326_Cartoon_-_On_On_(ft__Daniel_Levi).mp3 
        [status_artist_name] => Cartoon (feat. Daniel Levi) 
        [songinfoid] => 133 [title] => On & On (feat. Daniel Levi) 
        [array_to_string] => 
    ) 
    [1] => Array ( 
        [song_info_file_name] => Cartoon_-_On_On_(ft__Daniel_Levi).mp3 
        [song_info_revised_file_name] => 1510657326_Cartoon_-_On_On_(ft__Daniel_Levi).mp3 
        [status_artist_name] => American Authors 
        [songinfoid] => 133 
        [title] => On & On (feat. Daniel Levi) 
        [array_to_string] => 
    ) 
    [2] => Array ( 
        [song_info_file_name] => 01-Reverie_(feat__King_Deco).mp3 
        [song_info_revised_file_name] => 1510728747_01-Reverie_(feat__King_Deco).mp3 
        [status_artist_name] => Illenium 
        [songinfoid] => 136 
        [title] => Reverie (feat. King Deco) [array_to_string] => 
        ) 
    [3] => Array ( 
        [song_info_file_name] => 01-Reverie_(feat__King_Deco).mp3 
        [song_info_revised_file_name] => 1510728747_01-Reverie_(feat__King_Deco).mp3 
        [status_artist_name] => Cartoon (feat. Daniel Levi) 
        [songinfoid] => 136 
        [title] => Reverie (feat. King Deco) 
        [array_to_string] => 
    ) 
    [4] => Array ( 
        [song_info_file_name] => 01-Reverie_(feat__King_Deco).mp3 
        [song_info_revised_file_name] => 1510728747_01-Reverie_(feat__King_Deco).mp3 
        [status_artist_name] => American Authors 
        [songinfoid] => 136 
        [title] => Reverie (feat. King Deco) 
        [array_to_string] => 
    ) 
    [5] => Array ( 
        [song_info_file_name] => Cartoon_-_On_On_(ft__Daniel_Levi).mp3 
        [song_info_revised_file_name] => 1510657326_Cartoon_-_On_On_(ft__Daniel_Levi).mp3 
        [status_artist_name] => Illenium 
        [songinfoid] => 133 
        [title] => On & On (feat. Daniel Levi) 
        [array_to_string] => 
    ) 
    [6] => Array ( 
        [song_info_file_name] => American_Authors_-_Best_Day_Of_My_Life.mp3 
        [song_info_revised_file_name] => 1510540526_American_Authors_-_Best_Day_Of_My_Life.mp3 
        [status_artist_name] => Cartoon (feat. Daniel Levi) 
        [songinfoid] => 134 
        [title] => Best Day of My Life 
        [array_to_string] => Mix, Half, Alternative, Mid 
    ) 
    [7] => Array ( 
        [song_info_file_name] => American_Authors_-_Best_Day_Of_My_Life.mp3 
        [song_info_revised_file_name] => 1510540526_American_Authors_-_Best_Day_Of_My_Life.mp3 
        [status_artist_name] => American Authors 
        [songinfoid] => 134 
        [title] => Best Day of My Life [array_to_string] => Mix, Half, Alternative, Mid 
    ) 
    [8] => Array ( 
        [song_info_file_name] => American_Authors_-_Best_Day_Of_My_Life.mp3 
        [song_info_revised_file_name] => 1510540526_American_Authors_-_Best_Day_Of_My_Life.mp3 
        [status_artist_name] => Illenium 
        [songinfoid] => 134 
        [title] => Best Day of My Life 
        [array_to_string] => Mix, Mix, Half, Half, Alternative, Alternative, Mid, Mid 
    ) 
)
```

Comment: give your result array in print_r();

Comment: I updated the question with the result. welp what happened is it duplicated everything inside song_info

Comment: this is postgre isn't it ?

Comment: @sintakonte yes. this is postgre

Comment: You should change your join in query

Comment: do you have example? @AnandPandey

Comment: please change join type 'left' to 'inner' so if the condition is meet than it will show the result otherwise not.

Comment: tried. I'm not getting results.

Comment: that means your query not matched the condition

Comment: not matched the condition? the data I'm using are all in the database and the system itself

Comment: guess you're not getting the point. I want to display one song with multiple writers and publisher in one row.

Comment: @RealRich: I want that you check this query in phpmyadmin and give me the result as array what you get.

Comment: Have you checked?

Answer (score 0):

Well after a few minutes of brain storming I found a way to be able to fix this one. Thank you for those who commented. btw sorry to tag mysql but I was using postgresql. here's my solution for future purposes.

```
 public function get_shareable_songs_playlist($playlist_id)
{
    $this->db->select("si.songinfoid,
    si.filename,
    si.revised_filename,
    si.title,

    array_to_string(
        ARRAY(
            select status_artist_name from status s where s.song_info_id = si.songinfoid  
        ),

    '/'
    ) AS artist,

    array_to_string(
        ARRAY(
            select c.composer_name from composer c, song_composer sc where c.composer_id = sc.composer_id AND sc.song_info_id = si.songinfoid  
        ),

    '/'
    ) AS composer,

    array_to_string(
        ARRAY(
            select p.publisher_name from publisher p, composer c, song_composer sc where p.publisher_id = c.publisher_id AND c.composer_id = sc.composer_id AND sc.song_info_id = si.songinfoid  
        ),

    '/'
    ) AS publisher,

    array_to_string(
        ARRAY(
            select s.tag_name from song_tags s, song_info_tags sit where s.tag_id = sit.tag_id AND sit.song_info_id = si.songinfoid AND sit.info_tag_delete_flag = 0
        ),

    '/'
    ) AS tags,
    sp.playlist_id");
    $this->db->from("(SELECT song_info_id AS songinfoid, song_info_file_name AS filename, song_info_revised_file_name AS revised_filename, song_info_original_title AS title FROM song_info si GROUP BY song_info_id)si");
    $this->db->join('songs_in_playlist sp', 'sp.song_info_id = si.songinfoid');
    $this->db->join('playlist play', 'sp.playlist_id = play.playlist_id');
$this->db->where('sp.playlist_id', $playlist_id);
$this->db->where('play.playlist_share', 1);
$query = $this->db->get();

return $query->result_array();
}
```